# How to get a int with scanf()

Tags: c

```
void pedir_diag(int* diag){
  scanf("%i", &diag);
}

int main() {
  int number;

  pedir_diag(&number);

  return 0;
}
```

When I compile introduce an integer and expect that number int variable in the main have the value introduced but is not set

I have this, in my code but i am not able to set diag variable with scanf() function.

Comment: shouldn't it be `scanf("%i", diag);`? Are you trying to store the input value into an `int` at the address `diag`?

Comment: it doesnt work.

Comment: "It doesnt work" is not a description of the problem really.

Comment: I mean that especific case that he said. An trying to set  any of the types to return a value with a void function int * float* etc. anyways i will change it in the title.

Comment: You should edit to include a [mcve] showing how you're actually using the function, and include what input you expect to get, and what you get instead. Or, any compiler errors.

Answer (score 7):

`diag` is already a pointer so no need for the address-of operator (`&`) in the call to `scanf()`:

```
void pedir_diag(int *diag)
{
    scanf("%d", diag);
}
```

But to do it that way is kinda stupid. You have no way to check for erroneous input.
Better:

```
#include <stdbool.h>

bool pedir_diag(int *diag)
{
    return scanf("%d", diag) == 1;  // *)
}
```

*) `scanf()` returns the number of successful conversions, so if the number of successful conversions is 1 we return `true`.

Usage:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int foo;

    if (!pedir_diag(&foo)) {
        fputs("Input error :(\n\n", stderr);
    }
    else {
        // have fun with foo
    }
}
```

Comment: Never knew that `bool ` is available in `C`, Thanks

Comment: @Mayur It's basically an integral type that defines `bool`. But `<stdbool.h>` defines `bool`, `true` and `false` since C99 if my memory serves me correctly.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to use `scanf` through your entire coding life is by remembering the following rule

```
scanf("%[direction_of_what_to_scan][special format character]",
    Pointer_on_some_memory_location);
```

What `scanf` does is that it stores what the input was (with some length restrictions) to a memory address.  So, either:

```
int n1;
scanf("%d",&n); //which means the address of variable n1 in memory
```

or

```
int *n2 = &n1;
scanf("%d",n) // &doesn't need to be used cause n2 is now already pointer to an integer
```

Both will are different implementations of the same thing, they differ to the part of using pointers,for which C is well-known,and even applicable these days.